# How does Word Task Pane Office Add-in display on the left?

Tags: office-addins, word-web-addins

We developed a Word web add-in using `html`+`js`, and inserted to Word. Our questions:

1. Does the add-in display on the left of the document? Right now, when click on the Task Pane button it will display on the right of the document.
2. How can I keep the add-in open when next time open the document?

Answer (score 1):

> Does the add-in display on the left of the document? Right now, when
>   click on the Task Pane button it will display on the right of the
>   document.

It displays the Task Pane on the right side of the document for left to right reading languages. If it's a right to left reading language (like hebrew) it should open it on the right side. So it's not configurable by the developer.

> How can I keep the add-in open when next time open the document?

Check this link out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/automatically-open-a-task-pane-with-a-document

You need to name the taskpane id that you want to automatically open as

```
Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument
```

so your manifest should include a snippet like:

```
<Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
    <TaskpaneId>Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument</TaskpaneId>
    <SourceLocation resid="Contoso.Taskpane.Url" />
</Action>
```

and in your code you should enable the auto-loading with the following snippet:

```
Office.context.document.settings.set("Office.AutoShowTaskpaneWithDocument", true);
Office.context.document.settings.saveAsync();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. In taskpanes.xml we can see that there's property called dockstate can control the taskpane display left or right, is there a function of JavaScript API to set its value?

Comment: Can you point me to taskpanes.xml file? You can't (shouldn't be able to) change the docking state of the Office add-ins through your manifest file.

Comment: Also - I'd appreciate the green tick you think it answered your question :)